# HTML/CSS How do I make all the element of each box aligned?

Tags: html, css

[how i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFn8T.png)

[how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql697.png)

```css
.row2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.til-col {
  flex-basis: 32%;
  border: 7px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(92, 91, 91, 0.2);
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.til-col img {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 12px 34px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #012a5d;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row2">
  <div class="til-col">
    <img src="images/Home/Layer 2-2.svg">
    <p>Interact with a TIL timeline showing key moments and events over the years</p>
    <a href="classroom.html" class="button">
      <h3>TIL Story</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="til-col">
    <img src="images/Home/Progress.svg">
    <p>Discover projects and initiatives that have launched out of TIL to support innovation in learning spaces</p>
    <a href="classroom.html" class="button">
      <h3>Projects</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="til-col">
    <img src="images/Home/Report_icons-02 1.svg">
    <p>See the transformation of classroom spaces and follow progress over stages of the redesign process</p>
    <a href="classroom.html" class="button">
      <h3>Classroom Redesign</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the image of each box aligned with each other, same with the text and the button, like it is presented in the image. Yet everything would follow right after the image, the text ends. I also want to uniform the size of the image, without messing up the proportion, but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: You could layout each til-col as a grid with say 1fr 3fr 1fr template rows.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding the below styles to ".til-col" class will achieve the expected result

```
display: flex;
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

P.S. I don't think CSS have something to let you horzionally align several child elements from different blocks.

```css
.row2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: stretch;
}


.til-col {
  display:flex;
  flex-basis: 32%;
  border: 7px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(92, 91, 91, 0.2);
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.til-col img {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.til-col > p{
padding-bottom:40px;

}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 12px 34px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #012a5d;
   position: absolute;
   bottom:20px;

  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row2">
  <div class="til-col">
    <img src="images/Home/Layer 2-2.svg">
    <p>Interact with a TIL timeline showing key moments and events over the years</p>
    <a href="classroom.html" class="button">
      <h3>TIL Story</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="til-col">
    <img src="images/Home/Progress.svg">
    <p>Discover projects and initiatives that have launched out of TIL to support innovation in learning spaces</p>
    <a href="classroom.html" class="button">
      <h3>Projects</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="til-col">
    <img src="images/Home/Report_icons-02 1.svg">
    <p>See the transformation of classroom spaces and follow progress over stages of the redesign process</p>
    <a href="classroom.html" class="button">
      <h3>Classroom Redesign</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below code for solution

```css
.row2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.til-col {
  flex-basis: 32%;
  border: 7px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(92, 91, 91, 0.2);
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;

}

.til-col img {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.icon{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 34px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #012a5d;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row2">
  <div class="til-col">
    <div class="til-col-head">
        <div class="icon"><img src="https://dynamic.brandcrowd.com/asset/logo/2a056b05-ac9b-404f-a619-eba59f92ef48/logo-search-grid-1x?v=637631474641000000"></div>
        <p>Interact with a TIL timeline showing key moments and events over the years</p>
    </div>
    <a href="classroom.html" class="button">
      <h3>TIL Story</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="til-col">
    <div class="til-col-head">
        <div class="icon"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/109/109733.png"></div>
        <p>Discover projects and initiatives that have launched out of TIL to support innovation in learning spaces</p>
    </div>
    <a href="classroom.html" class="button">
      <h3>Projects</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="til-col">
    <div class="til-col-head">
        <div class="icon"><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1268/0*2pi-PJAAVse41Ovk.png"></div>
        <p>See the transformation of classroom spaces and follow progress over stages of the redesign process</p>
    </div>
    <a href="classroom.html" class="button">
      <h3>Classroom Redesign</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```